# DVR RW drive not recognized on my laptop

Tags: dvd

I installed elementary OS on my EliteBook from a USB stick, and I'm not able to see my DVD RW drive.

Could you please help me? I tried listing `ls /dev` but nothing is visible... :-/

Thank you

Comment: Please add the output you get when running `lsblk` from the terminal and any further information about the model of the laptop.

Comment: To answer this question as well as possible we need the exact computer model as well as the output of the `lsblk` command for example